# Detect Linebreak Index in Textbox

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a multiline textbox in my wpf application:

```
<TextBox
    x:Name="TextBoxText"
    Height="auto"
    Margin="{StaticResource ThicknessMarginTextBox}"
    VerticalAlignment="Top"
    MaxLines="5"
    Text="{Binding TextInputMultiline, Path=Text, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
    TextWrapping="Wrap" />
```

how can i get the character index or position of a linebreak?

Comment: Have you saw the [Q](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5720302/wpf-get-wrapped-text-out-of-a-textbox)?

Comment: the link to the needed classes in this question are dead...

Comment: [Advanced Text Formatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/advanced-text-formatting)

Comment: [Advanced Text Formatting Sample](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms771407(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: let me know if it doesn't help

Comment: this doesn't help me...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46215326/indentation-of-second-line-in-wpf-textformatter

Comment: if it still doesn't help maybe you can ping me in [WPF chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18165/wpf)?