# Full justify of last line in WPF TextFormatter

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I'm making a WPF text-editor using `TextFormatter`. I need to justify the **last** line in each paragraph.

Something like that:

```
I need to justify the last line in each
paragraph I need to justify the last li
ne in each  paragraph I need to justify 
the  last line in each paragraph I need 
to    justify    the   last   line   in
```

how to make this happen?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Unfortunately you are out of luck. I needed this a few years ago and there was no option in wpf and apparently no way to work around or hack it.

Comment: Why don't you try to write a converter to achieve this?

Comment: How about this?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46215326/indentation-of-second-line-in-wpf-textformatter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `TextSource` implementation, in `GetTextRun` function, at the end of each paragraph return an `TextEmbeddedObject` object with very wide width, and with height 0.

This way you will force the last line to be justified.

```
class MyTextEmbeddedObject : TextEmbeddedObject
{
    public override LineBreakCondition BreakBefore => LineBreakCondition.BreakAlways;

    public override LineBreakCondition BreakAfter => LineBreakCondition.BreakRestrained;

    public override bool HasFixedSize => true;

    public override CharacterBufferReference CharacterBufferReference => throw new NotImplementedException();

    public override int Length => 1;

    public override TextRunProperties Properties => GenericTextParagraphProperties._defaultTextRunProperties;

    public override Rect ComputeBoundingBox(bool rightToLeft, bool sideways)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override void Draw(DrawingContext drawingContext, Point origin, bool rightToLeft, bool sideways)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override TextEmbeddedObjectMetrics Format(double remainingParagraphWidth)
    {
        return new TextEmbeddedObjectMetrics(10000 /* very wide width */, 0, 0);
    }
}
```